# In Scala, is there any mechanism for inheriting local method variables?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have

```
class Parent {

    def method() {
        var myvar = "test"
    }

}
```

Is there any mechanism for accessing myvar in child classes?

Edit:

I'm trying to build a DSL modeled upon an existing language.  That language has features such as

```
onTrade {
    if (price == ...) // will compile
}

onDayStart {
    if (price == ...) // will not compile
}
```

It is as if price is a global variable but there are compile time checks to make sure it is only used in the correct context. I was thinking one way to simulate this would be to have local variables that could be overridden in subclasses.  Something like

```
// Parent
onTrade {
    var price = ...
}

// Child
onTrade {
    if (price == ...)
    if (somethingelse == ...) // will not compile
}
```

Comment: Woah! Why should there be? That sounds like a *terrible* feature!

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to do. We will tell you how to do it a Scala way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution for your problem (though I don't see a way to get rid of `new`):

```
// parent
var onTrades = List[OnTrade]()
class OnTrade {
  var price = ...
  ...
  onTrades = this :: onTrades
}

// child
new OnTrade {
  if (price == ...) {...} // subclass constructor, will call OnTrade constructor first
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Not really. That's scope for you. If you want it to be visible at different levels, you should probably change the scope of the variable itself.

For example, if you want to define it at the class level, you can share it that way. Local variables wouldn't be local if they weren't actually, well, local.

Scopes are nested, from the most broad, to the most local. [Chapter 2, pg. 16 of the Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) covers "Identifiers, Names, and Scopes" which explains this in more technical detail.